# Deducing that two angles of a given triangle are less than $\pi/3$

Tags: trigonometry

Denote by $ABC$ the vertices of a triangle and let $Z$ be a point on $AC$ so that if we connect $B$ to $Z$ with a line segment $BZ$, it divides the triangle $ABC$ into two triangles $ABZ$ and $ZBC$.

If we know that $|BZ|\leq |AZ|$ and $|BZ| \leq |ZC|$ how can I conclude that $\angle BAC \leq \pi/3$ and $\angle BCA \leq \pi/3$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking to prove is not always true. To see this, consider the diagram below:

[image: Isosceles triangle]

For any $\frac{\pi}{6} \gt \epsilon \gt 0$, let $\measuredangle BAZ = \measuredangle ABZ = \frac{\pi}{3} + \epsilon$, so $|BZ| = |AZ|$. This also means $\measuredangle BZA = \frac{\pi}{3} - 2\epsilon$.

Next, extend $AZ$ to $C$ so $|ZC| \ge |BZ|$, plus join the points $B$ and $C$, such as shown below.

[image: Isosceles triangle extended to be the full triangle]

This triangle meets your conditions of $|BZ|\leq |AZ|$ and $|BZ| \leq |ZC|$, but with $\measuredangle BAC \gt \frac{\pi}{3}$.

However, here is some potentially useful limits you can prove. By the [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), you get

$$\frac{|BZ|}{\sin(\angle BAZ)} = \frac{|AZ|}{\sin(\angle ABZ)} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As $|BZ| \leq |AZ|$, this means $\sin(\angle BAZ) \leq \sin(\angle ABZ)$. Since $\sin(x)$ is an increasing function for $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $\measuredangle BAZ \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ (because, if it's $\geq \frac{\pi}{2}$ instead, then $|BZ|$ would need to be the largest side in $\triangle BAZ$), this means you have

$$\measuredangle BAZ \leq \measuredangle ABZ \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Similarly, you also have

$$\measuredangle BCZ \le \measuredangle CBZ \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

From the sum of angles in $\triangle ABC$ being $\pi$, you get

$$\measuredangle ABZ + \measuredangle CBZ = \pi - \measuredangle BAZ - \measuredangle BCZ \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Adding \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A}, plus using \eqref{eq4A}, gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\measuredangle BAZ + \measuredangle BCZ & \le \pi - \measuredangle BAZ - \measuredangle BCZ \\
2(\measuredangle BAZ + \measuredangle BCZ) & \le \pi \\
\measuredangle BAC + \measuredangle BCA & \le \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

and, as well,

$$\measuredangle BAC \le \frac{\pi}{4} \; \text{ and/or } \; \measuredangle BCA \le \frac{\pi}{4} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Since the sums of the $2$ angles must be less than or equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, you also get

$$\measuredangle ABC \ge \frac{\pi}{2} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Comment: Indeed, I see now. Thanks very much for the detailed answer.

Apparently I need more conditions then to guarantee the claim, in particular if in addition we require that $|BZ| \leq |BA|$ and $|BZ| \leq |BC|$ I believe then it works.